# SilverStripe Ajax and Page Controllers

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have a very short question regarding Silverstripe. I have not found a solution anyway on the internet or here. I currently have a form on SS4 that when submit it will run an AJax request and render new content (page). The problem I have is that the content does not display and it seems to be related to the fact that the content that is rendered in is managed by a different Page controller. So it could not find the content when rendering through Ajax from another page. How would I resolve this without refreshing the page ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

you would submit to the same page, which has a function to generate/return the new page. note that when submitting via ajax you need to include the FormAction button in the submitted fields.

Comment: hi, how do I include the FormAction button in the submitted fields ? I am having difficulties with form action through Ajax submit and rendering because I have 3 buttons back next and save. but they all triggers the same action (back action) after a new form is loaded through ajax which is weird.

Comment: Ajax doesn't include form buttons. When you click a button, you need to manually append the form action to the submitted data. If you don't append it, SS will assume you tried the first action, which in your case, is the "back" action.

For example, if the submit action is called "action_doSubmit"... 
`var formData = new FormData(form); formData.append('action_doSubmit', 'Submit'); $.post(url, formData );`